# Tensorboard Exporting Incomplete Scalar SVG

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

For reference, I am using:
Keras 2.2.4
Tensorflow GPU 1.12.0
Tensorboard 1.12.0

I have a bunch of scalar graphs in tensorboard I would like to export as an SVG. Unfortunately, this just doesn't seem to work. The SVG I get seems to be just the y axis and an error I can't make sense of, and that my googling doesn't seem to be helping with. For reference, here's the rendered SVG:

[SVG Render image link because I can't embed images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSoV1.png)

If there's anything else I can provide please let me know. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why my perfectly legitimate question got downvoted, but after hours of research I solved my problem.

Tensorflow 1.2's Tensorboard is broken like this. I installed a separate venv on which I installed TF 1.3 just for tensorboard. Then I was able to export an actually complete svg file.

Note to anyone reading this, TF 1.3 does *not* work with CUDA 6 at the time of writing.